# Density of semiprimes on short intervals

Tags: prime-numbers, semiprimes

Perhaps this is a trivial question, but I'm not an expert. Let

$$Q(m) = \bigl| \{ n : m\leq n \leq m + \log(m) \mbox{ and } n = p \cdot q\text{, where }p,q\text{ are prime} \} \bigr|$$

*i.e.*, $Q(m)$ is the size of the set containing the numbers between $m$ and $m + \log(m)$ that are the product of two primes.

What is the value of the limit:

$$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac{Q(m)}{\log(m)}$$

Comment: This is not a trivial question, no worries. First, would you know how to solve that for $n=p$ primes, instead of $n=pq$? Do you think we can?

Comment: @julien: for $n = p$ (n is prime) it should be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected size of $Q(m)$ is $\log\log m$ and so
$$
\liminf_{m\to\infty}\frac{Q(m)}{\log m}=0.
$$

I don't know that the $\limsup$ exists but it is probably 0.

Comment: why the expected size is $\log \log m$?

Comment: @Vor: There are $\sim n\log\log n/\log n$ semiprimes up to $n$ (a result of Landau), hence in each interval of length $\log n$ around $n$ there are on average $\sim\log\log n$ semiprimes.